Meaning of ほしいくらいもたないでも

わたしたちは、氷砂糖をほしいくらいもたないでも、きれいにすきとおった風をたべ、桃いろのうつくしい朝の日光をのむことができます。 

We, who wish for rock sugar but have none (??), may partake of the pleasantly crisp wind, and can drink instead of the peach-coloured light of the early morning.

This is the preface to the short story collection 注文の多い料理店 by 宮沢賢治. I understand the latter half fine, but what is up with the construction 「氷砂糖をほしいくらいもたないでも」? The above "translation" is my best guess.
If this is indeed 持たない, I am not aware of any constructions that would allow it to be followed by でも.

This expression was indeed puzzling to me, but ほしいくらい seems to be a way of saying 欲しいだけ or 好きなだけ ("as much as one wishes") in Tohoku dialects. I found an article that discusses this expression:
小島聡子. 標準語と宮沢賢治―方言と標準語のはざまで. 賢治学第四輯 (2017) (PDF)

この「ほしいくらい」という部分は、東京方言話者の筆者にとって、かなり違和感がある。ここで「ほしいくらい」は文脈から推察しておそらく「すきなだけ」あるいは「ほしいだけ」などという言い回しに相当するのではないかとは考えられるが、微妙にニュアンスが違うのではないかという気もしていた。
岩手大学の大学院生たち数人に聞いてみたところ、岩手県・秋田県・青森県出身の学生たちはこの表現に違和感はもたないということであった。地元の集まりなどでお菓子の入れ物のそばに「ほしいくらい取りなさい」などと書いであったりするという証言も得た。あるいは「すきなくらい」という言い方もあるという。
学生たちに「ほしいくらい」はあまり他所では聞かないということを伝えると、一様に驚いた様子であった。学生たちにはこの表現が方言だという意識はないということであろう。

So 氷砂糖をほしいくらいもたないでも means "Even if you don't have/own as much rock sugar as you want".

Thanks for the answer. Additionally, I was wondering whether 〜ないでも here is natural — I was expecting もたなくても, but is the nuance of that expression different?

@jogloran もたなくても would be slightly more natural, but もたないでも is okay. Miyazawa's Japanese is somewhat unique, partly because he's a fairy tale author and a dialect speaker. It might be better not to rely on his Japanese too much as a reference of modern Japanese.
